# Populating dropdown list from Text file, value is being set as incrementing number instead of content

Tags: php, forms

I've managed to pull together a way to populate a 'Country' dropdown menu from a txt file, with all of the options on a line each.

The value of each item is given an incrementing number, and passes this through fine.

But how can I pass through the contents of the line from the text file, without having to create a massive switch for each of the number values, to set the country?

```
<select class="country-select" name="country" tabindex = '9' >
<?php
$lines = file( 'country-list.txt' );
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines);$i++) {
        echo '<option value=' . ($i + 1) . '>' . $lines[$i] . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>

$name       = clearData($_POST["name"]);
$country    = ($_POST["country"]);
$phone      = ($_POST["phone"]);
```

A small portion of my country file:

```
Your Country
-
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antarctica
Antigua/Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
Australia
```

It's worth saying, that the email response I receive, shows the number of the value. Which is the line number in the text file, and that corresponds to the correct country chosen in the dropdown menu. So it is selecting and passing through the correct country.

Comment: can you post a sample of 'country-list.txt' ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; do you want the value of `$country` to be the name of the selected country?

If so, what's stopping you from just doing `$country = $lines[$_POST["country"]];`

Comment: Pretty much, yes. The only way I can think of doing it simply, is creating a long switch for each line number, and setting that manually as the country name.

Comment: I edited my above comment with a suggestion before I saw your response.  Does that work?

Comment: No, that returns 'NULL'. I may just stick with the switch if I can get it working.

Comment: The value of `$lines` probably doesn't exist in the current scope.  Make sure you duplicate the line `$lines = file( 'country-list.txt' );` immediately above the code I previously suggested.  This will ensure the file is read and that the array is created with the appropriate values.

Comment: That does work, thanks for that.. However it seems to be returning the line below the line selected. Eg. if I select the first item, it will return the second item. If I select the 14th item, it will return the 15th item. Is that anything to do with setting the value of `$i`?

Comment: I've submitted an answer below that hopefully solves your issue (and also corrects the issue you just mentioned; which was a bit of an oversight on my part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these functions; it should work for your purposes.

```
// Get an array containing valid countries.
function GetCountries()
{
    $lines = file('country-list.txt');
    return $lines;
}

// Get the name of the country from the specified line number (its index in the array)
function GetCountryName($countryIndex)
{
    $countries = GetCountries();
    // It looks like your values for the <select> elements are not zero-based, so you might want to apply that modification here.  Uncomment the following line if that is the case.
    // $countryIndex = $countryIndex - 1;
    $countryName = $countries[$countryIndex];
    return $countryName;
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, although after uncommenting that `$countryName` line, I needed to change the value to `- 1`

Comment: Silly me, tried to fix the issue and did the opposite of what needed to be done.  I'll go ahead and update my answer for the sake of correctness.